# Can I completely turn off the fans on a MacBook Pro (0 RPM)

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, temperature, power-management

I would like to know if there is a utility to completely turn off the fans.

Currently, when completely idle, fans are showing 2000 and 2100 RPM.
Although this is probably not recommended, I would like to have the option to completely shut them down.

Software such as [1](https://www.crystalidea.com/macs-fan-control) enable fan control but only lets you lower the RPM to the minimum set by Apple (which is 2000 and 2100 for each fan respectively),but I’m looking for an off switch.

When the CPU is idling, this should help preserve some battery life, and prevent dust from accumulating.

*I am fully aware that this can damage the system and am not recommending this to anyone*.

The question is whether this **could** be done and not whether this **should** be done.

Comment: .. and cause logic board failure.

Comment: The question is *can* this be done, and not *should* this be done

Comment: The `smc-command` tool included with `smcFanControl` has no limits. It should do what you need without changing the code. Be careful!

Comment: Perfect, @GrahamMiln, `smc-command` is the answer I was looking for

Comment: Appreciate the downvotes, (and the answers of course). Remember, **you** own your computer, not Apple. You should be able to perform basic things like controlling the fans on your computer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Disabling the fans is not recommended but appears possible through the software below:

> ## [smc-command](https://github.com/hholtmann/smcFanControl/tree/master/smc-command)
>
> This tool will allow you to write values to the SMC which could irreversably damage your computer.
>
> ...
>
> This program will allow you to read and write values to the SMC using the AppleSMC kernel
>   extension.  The purpose of this is to show how to talk to the controller.

**smcFanControl** is a graphical interface for `sic-command` with additional safely limits:

> ## [smcFanControl](https://github.com/hholtmann/smcFanControl)
>
> smcFanControl lets the user set a minimum speed for built-in fans. It allows you to increase your minimum fan speed to make your Intel Mac run cooler. In order to not damage your machine, smcFanControl does not let you set a minimum speed to a value below Apple's defaults.

Being open source, you could remove the minimum limits imposed by `smcFanControl`.

[image: smcFanControl screenshot]

Comment: Interestingly `smc-control` also returns an error when attempting to pass a value under 1000, but this can probably be easily changed in code